# /bin/bash: line 120: docker: command not found

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, gitlab

Getting the error in Gitlab, when I was using below gitlab-ci.yaml
troubleshoot and investigated by changing the image and permissions & ownership at the OS level for docker file, but it didn't help

```
/bin/bash: line 120: docker: command not found
```

when executing the job from GitLab, we get the error.
.gitlab-ci.yaml

```
stages:
    - build-stage
    - deploy-stage

image: docker

build:
    script:
        - docker --version
        - docker build -t pyapp . 
    tags:
        - linux
    stage: build-stage

deploy:
    script:
        - docker stop python-container || true && docker rm python-container || true
        - docker run -d --name python-container -p 80:8080 pyapp
        - echo "Commit author is:" $CI_COMMIT_AUTHOR 

    tags:
        - linux
    stage: deploy-stage
```

Comment: Please post your gitlab-ci.yaml and rephrase your question.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a lot of time, earlier I thought it could be an issue with the docker engine or permissions or something with the OS platform.
while running the
`gitlab-runner register`
We need to provide or modify the `executor`, in my case earlier it was docker I changed it to `shell` and it worked for me